# grid.arrange - side-by-side plots being squished to small size in r markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm having an issue trying to use grid.arrange to arrange multiple plots in an RMarkdown document (output to html).

Without being able to post a replicable example of the plots themselves, here's the basic issue:

I can arrange two plots, side-by-side, reasonably well:

```
grid.arrange(
  plot1,
  plot2,
  ncol=2,
  top = "Title of the page"
)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

But as soon as I try to add two more plots:

```
grid.arrange(
  plot1,
  plot2,
  plot3,
  ncol=2,
  top = "Title of the page"
)
```

grid.arrange starts to squish the plots:

[image]

I've tried adding a `heights`parameter to `grid.arrange`, but no luck.  Basically, I just want a reasonable looking arrangement of graphs that doesn't squish or distort them in the RMarkdown doc.

Comment: in RMD, you can change the height and width of each of the components i.e. ```{r your plot, fig.height = 14, fig.width = 16, fig.align = "center"}

Comment: yeah, i tried that, but it seems to mess with the resolution of my plots if I change the fig.width and height

Comment: maybe try with `patchwork`

Comment: actually, your suggestion looks reasonable when output on html doc.  hmmm.

Comment: So, when I change the figure height and width, the text seems to get way shrunk.

Comment: Hi DiamondJoe. Please try to stick to technical writing here, and refrain from adding chatty or conversational material here. Questions and answers are kept essentially forever here, and thus we generally like to curate them in a similar way tp documentation, rather than presenting them as snapshots of a chatroom.

Comment: Could you please share your code so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I'm not reproducing the problem. What type of plots are you using? What styles and output options are you using? BTW, the figure height and width are not 'per plot' with `grid.arrange`.  It's the size of the `grid.arrange` object. `html_document` defaults to some wicked margins. (You said `html` but there are many, many HTML options in RMD.) For the margin issue:  `<style>.main-container{max-width: unset;}</style>`. If you are using `flex_dashboard`, try using `vertical_layout: scroll`. (Default is `fill`.)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the the problem is not in the functions themselves, but in the markdown used to establish the chunk. By default, the discrete output of images and plots from a chunk are displayed in a window of a specific size, and are scaled to fit it, so setting the height variable within the function itself, as you noted, does not work, and changing to a slightly different function, as has been suggested, also is unlikely to do much.
The solution is to change the figure height of the output for the chunk itself, using the `fig.height` and related chunk options.
Here is specifically how I did it:

> ````
> ```{r my-attempt, fig.height=9}
> grid.arrange(
>   plot1,
>   plot2,
>   plot3,
>   ncol = 2,
>   top = "Title of the page"
> ) 
> ```
> ````

This information can be found on [this page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html) of the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/)

Edit: I seem to have overlooked that this solution was mentioned in the comments, and the asker already expressed reservations about it, specifically around effects on resolution. I have not experienced problems like that in my replication attempt, but of course I don't have the original plots. *I still think that the solution offered here is probably the best simple way to resolve the issue*, so I will be leaving this up.

Comment: If you want to preserve the aspect ratios of the graphs, set the 2x2 plot to be twice the height of the 1x1. To find the dimensions, right click on the html and save the figure to png, open properties > details > dimensions > divide by 300 dpi to get in inches.

For my single plot it was 4.48 x 3.2 (width x height inches), so setting `{r plot4, fig.height = 3.2 * 2}` for the 2x2 plot and `fig.height = 3.2` for the 2x1 retains the aspect ratio of a single plot in both; or if you are basing off the 2x1 plot in the question, then you would do `3.2 * 4` for the height

Answer (score 0):

You could try another function `ggarrange` from the `ggpubr` package.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(
    plot1,
    plot2,
    plot3,
    common.legend = TRUE)
```

*Edit: misspelled function